# How do I exclude an object from AO in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, shaders, shadows

I have a scene where black text is on a gray surface.  With AO, this makes the text are to read.  I want to eliminate AO on the gray surface so I can see the black text, but keep it in other details in the scene.

How do I achieve this effect in Blender Cycles?

Comment: How are you applying your AO at the moment?

Comment: You could render the text on a separate render layer and composit it over the main render

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm applying it through nodes!

Comment: @dixiepig Yes, this is an option I've heard, but I wanted to further pursue this topic to see if there's an another easier way!

Comment: Cycles does AO 'naturally' .. it samples the environment for bounced diffuse light, so those areas with less exposure to it (crevices, corners) will be darker, as they are in real life. So your answer will probably lie in a combination of lighting, switching shadow-casting on or off, (and AO, if necessary) for your desired effect. I think an image of your problem would really help with this one.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for your comment!  Unfortunately the client requires that no work can't be posted until the illustration is released to the advertising agency.  I might make a simulation of what is going on though to get around this problem.

Comment: Yup...put up a dummy with the same materials and lighting, if you can.